# Eliminating Gamma from result of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I think the following integration result can be shown without `Gamma`.

Can anyone explain

1. Why Mathematica Uses `Gamma`.
2. How to simplify the result to eliminate `Gamma`.

[image]

code:

```
Simplify[Integrate[(x/c)^(2/(1 - b)), {x, 0, 1/b}], Assumptions -> {1 > b > 0, c > 0}]
```

Comment: Please do not post images of your work. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Your integral diverges for `0<b<1` and so Mathematica is returning the principal value.

Comment: @ Carl Woll, if I change 2/(1-b) to 1/(1-b), the integral is also diverging? but there is no Gamma in the result, could you elaborate more on it?

Comment: Try this: `Assuming[{1 > b > 0, c > 0}, 
 Integrate[(x/c)^(2/(1 - b)), {x, 0, 1/b}]]`

Comment: @ Mariusz Iwaniuk,  thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Integrate[(x/c)^(2/(1 - b)), {x, 0, 1/b}, 
 Assumptions -> {1 > b > 0, c > 0}]

(* ((-1 + b) (b c)^(2/(-1 + b)))/((-3 + b) b) *)
```

Have fun!